# one to many association ,table not associate ,

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create my databse withe hibernate, i cerated my tables builduing and customer but when i want to associate one to many ( one building have many customer ) i have this problem,

```
alter table CUSTOMER add constraint FK52C76FDE6049D2D3 foreign key (BUILDING_ID) references BUILDING
```

i'm using mysql server and hibernate for the mapping, those are my java.classes ,
the fist one is the Building.java

```
package com.tunisiana.app.building.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.tunisiana.app.customer.model.Customer;
import com.tunisiana.app.places.model.City;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUILDING")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true, dynamicInsert = true)
public class Building implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7781368778417866160L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BUILDING_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer buildingId;

    @Column(name = "ADRESS", nullable = false)
    private String buildingAdress;

    @Column(name = "X", nullable = false)
    private Integer buildingX;

    @Column(name = "Y", nullable = false)
    private Integer buildingY;

    @Column(name = "FLOOR", nullable = false)
    private Integer buildingFloor;

    @Column(name = "HEIGHT_OF_FLOOR", nullable = false)
    private Double buildingHeightOfFloor;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_FIBER", nullable = true)
    private Integer buildingNumberOfFiber;

    @Column(name = "Type", nullable = true)
    private String buildingType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY", nullable = false)
    private City city;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "building")
    private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>(0);

    public Building() {
        super();
    }

    public Building(Integer buildingId) {
        super();
        this.buildingId = buildingId;
    }


    public Building(Integer buildingId, String buildingAdress,
            Integer buildingX, Integer buildingY, Integer buildingFloor,
            Double buildingHeightOfFloor, Integer buildingNumberOfFiber,
            String buildingType) {
        super();
        this.buildingId = buildingId;
        this.buildingAdress = buildingAdress;
        this.buildingX = buildingX;
        this.buildingY = buildingY;
        this.buildingFloor = buildingFloor;
        this.buildingHeightOfFloor = buildingHeightOfFloor;
        this.buildingNumberOfFiber = buildingNumberOfFiber;
        this.buildingType = buildingType;
    }



    public Building(Integer buildingId, String buildingAdress,
            Integer buildingX, Integer buildingY, Integer buildingFloor,
            Double buildingHeightOfFloor, Integer buildingNumberOfFiber,
            String buildingType, City city, Set<Customer> customers) {
        super();
        this.buildingId = buildingId;
        this.buildingAdress = buildingAdress;
        this.buildingX = buildingX;
        this.buildingY = buildingY;
        this.buildingFloor = buildingFloor;
        this.buildingHeightOfFloor = buildingHeightOfFloor;
        this.buildingNumberOfFiber = buildingNumberOfFiber;
        this.buildingType = buildingType;
        this.city = city;
        this.customers = customers;
    }

    public Integer getBuildingId() {
        return buildingId;
    }

    public void setBuildingId(Integer buildingId) {
        this.buildingId = buildingId;
    }

    public String getBuildingAdress() {
        return buildingAdress;
    }

    public void setBuildingAdress(String buildingAdress) {
        this.buildingAdress = buildingAdress;
    }

    public Integer getBuildingX() {
        return buildingX;
    }

    public void setBuildingX(Integer buildingX) {
        this.buildingX = buildingX;
    }

    public Integer getBuildingY() {
        return buildingY;
    }

    public void setBuildingY(Integer buildingY) {
        this.buildingY = buildingY;
    }

    public Integer getBuildingFloor() {
        return buildingFloor;
    }

    public void setBuildingFloor(Integer buildingFloor) {
        this.buildingFloor = buildingFloor;
    }

    public Double getBuildingHeightOfFloor() {
        return buildingHeightOfFloor;
    }

    public void setBuildingHeightOfFloor(Double buildingHeightOfFloor) {
        this.buildingHeightOfFloor = buildingHeightOfFloor;
    }

    public Integer getBuildingNumberOfFiber() {
        return buildingNumberOfFiber;
    }

    public void setBuildingNumberOfFiber(Integer buildingNumberOfFiber) {
        this.buildingNumberOfFiber = buildingNumberOfFiber;
    }

    public String getBuildingType() {
        return buildingType;
    }

    public void setBuildingType(String buildingType) {
        this.buildingType = buildingType;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Set<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(Set<Customer> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Building [buildingId=" + buildingId + ", buildingAdress="
                + ", buildingX=" + buildingX + ", buildingY=" + buildingY
                + ", buildingFloor=" + buildingFloor
                + ", buildingHeightOfFloor=" + buildingHeightOfFloor
                + ", buildingNumberOfFiber=" + buildingNumberOfFiber
                + ", buildingType=" + buildingType + "]";
    }



}
```

and this is my Customer.java

```
package com.tunisiana.app.customer.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.tunisiana.app.building.model.Building;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true, dynamicInsert = true)
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6690383671585902911L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CIN", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer customerCIN;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String customerName;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    private String customerPhoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_TYPE", nullable = false)
    private String customerType;

    @Column(name = "SUBSCRIPTION", nullable = true)
    private String customerSubscription;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_FIBER", nullable = false)
    private Integer customerNumberOfFiber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUILDING_ID", nullable = false)
    private Building building;

    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

    public Customer(Integer customerCIN) {
        super();
        this.customerCIN = customerCIN;
    }

    public Customer(Integer customerCIN, String customerName,
            String customerPhoneNumber, String customerType,
            String customerSubscription, Integer customerNumberOfFiber,
            Building building) {
        super();
        this.customerCIN = customerCIN;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.customerPhoneNumber = customerPhoneNumber;
        this.customerType = customerType;
        this.customerSubscription = customerSubscription;
        this.customerNumberOfFiber = customerNumberOfFiber;
        this.building = building;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerCIN() {
        return customerCIN;
    }

    public void setCustomerCIN(Integer customerCIN) {
        this.customerCIN = customerCIN;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerPhoneNumber() {
        return customerPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomerPhoneNumber(String customerPhoneNumber) {
        this.customerPhoneNumber = customerPhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCustomerType() {
        return customerType;
    }

    public void setCustomerType(String customerType) {
        this.customerType = customerType;
    }

    public String getCustomerSubscription() {
        return customerSubscription;
    }

    public void setCustomerSubscription(String customerSubscription) {
        this.customerSubscription = customerSubscription;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerNumberOfFiber() {
        return customerNumberOfFiber;
    }

    public void setCustomerNumberOfFiber(Integer customerNumberOfFiber) {
        this.customerNumberOfFiber = customerNumberOfFiber;
    }

    public Building getBuilding() {
        return building;
    }

    public void setBuilding(Building building) {
        this.building = building;
    }   


}
```

and when i ran it i have always this problem

```
juin 13, 2014 9:39:33 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table CUSTOMER add constraint FK52C76FDE6049D2D3 foreign key (BUILDING_ID) references BUILDING
juin 13, 2014 9:39:33 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

i don't know where is the problem !! could you please help me !!

Comment: add one variable with @Column(name = "BUILDING_ID") and add insertable=false,updatebale=false in JoinColumn.

Comment: Should i add @Column(name ="Building_ID) and add insertable=false,updatebale=false in JoinColumn (in the Customer.java !! or the Building.java !!) please i'm a biginner, could you explane to me , thks for your help,

Comment: But in my database, the Column BUILDING_ID exist in the table customer, and the problem it's not a forein key,

Comment: remove `nullable=false` from `@JoinColumn(name = "BUILDING_ID", nullable = false)`

Comment: also it's not working !!, the tables and column are created but there is no relation between the table, "BUILDING_ID" is cerated in the table city but it's not a forein key,